# Using ActionLink parameters with button onclick ?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, html5-canvas

Straight forword I think just can't find the syntax...

I have an ActionLink which uses an id property,

```
  <td style="padding-right:35px">@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditUser", new { @id = user.ID.ToString("N") }, new { @class = "btn yellow"})</td>
```

Basically I want to change this to a btn, but I am not sure how to pass the id parameter , I think it's something like this....

```
 <button type="button" class="btn blue" id="user.ID.ToString("N")" onclick="location.href='ReferralTarget/EditUser'"><i class="icon-edit"> Edit</button>
```

Where ReferralTarget is my control and EditUser my actionResult..
Please note this is an ASP.NET MVC4 application using Razor2 views...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn blue" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("EditUser", "ReferralTarget", new { @id = user.ID }'"><i class="icon-edit"> Edit</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, minor change and works perfectly, if this is yr area could I ask how I might get an icon to appear inline with text in the following...it has to be an input, <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" class="btn green">@*<i class="icon-ok"></i>*@

Comment: the minor change was....<td><button type="button" class="btn blue" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("EditUser", new { @id = user.ID })'"><i class="icon-edit"></i> Edit</button></td>

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this if you like the jquery route:

```
@functions
{

    private string GetUserId()
    {
         //I'm not sure where you are getting user from, but if it's from the model,
         //you would need to change this to something like @Model.something....
         return user.ID;
    }

}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#edit').click(function() {
            location.href = "ReferralTarget/EditUser/" + "@GetUserId()";
        });
    });
</script>

<input type="button" id="edit" value="edit" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy trick-

Use jqueryUi, and justdo `$("#linkid").button()`, and style it how ever u want